# Foreign key reference issue faced during database load testing using JMeter for JDBC requests in SQL Server

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, transactions, foreign-keys, sql-server-2019

The issue appears for around 30 concurrent threads/users running at time.

Setup for JDBC Connection configuration is as below:
Auto Commit is set to false.
Transaction Isolation is set to TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED (As per internal Application settting)

The JDBC request for parent and child are/should be wrapped in a single transaction and should be committed atomically. Tested for single user/thread and it works fine and commits the parent and child transaction atomically.

During debugging, it is noticed that the parent record gets inserted first in a transaction but subsequent child insert fails giving foreign key reference error by following the below queries.

** Below queries are run in SSMS to track the inserts and transactions during load test running in JMeter

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT * FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE ID = NEW_ID; -- Returns one record

SELECT * FROM CHILD_TABLE WHERE ID = NEW_ID; -- Returns one record

After some moment

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
SELECT * FROM PARENT_TABLE WHERE ID = NEW_ID; -- No record

SELECT * FROM CHILD_TABLE WHERE ID = NEW_ID; -- No record

Sometimes, it inserts one or two child record but fails insert for subsequent child records with same foreign key reference error.

Ran SQL trace with Error Log, Exception, Deadlock Graph, Lock Aquired, Lock Release, Lock Timeout but no clue what is going wrong.

Added constant timer for the JDBC sampler to delay the insertion to child but no progress. Also, delayed the parent sampler while inserting records in the parent table but no progress.

Can anybody help me out here?

I tried copying the scripts Jmeter produced during runs and inserted the parent record first and then the failed child records through SSMS and it worked without any fail.

It should work the same way when running through JMeter without any foreign key reference issues

Comment: Also, What should be the setting for "Pool Prepared Statements"? Mine is set to -1.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the proper way of setting transaction isolation is not via SQL but rather via [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration):

   [image]
2. The same is for "Commit", by default JMeter commits JDBC Request statements immediately, if you want to run them in batch you should set "Auto Commit" to `False` and perform the commit using a separate JDBC Request sampler:

   [image]

More information: [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter)

Comment: I have done the setup in the same way. I have set the transaction isolation level to read uncommitted in the JDBC connection configuration. Auto commit is also set to false and commit is done in batches

Comment: What should be the setting for "Pool Prepared Statements"? Mine is set to -1.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is now fixed. It was due to controlled throughput, which eventually slowed down the whole process, i.e., the delay between each request sampler execution. The total execution time taken for Starting the transaction, Inserting the Header, Inserting Lines, and finally committing took around 42 secs. It started running fine when the delay was reduced and brought to below 30 secs. All I need to do is make it run faster rather than slow down.